# Proof of existence of minima and maxima

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

I am reading the textbook Vector Calculus by J. Hubbard H. Hubbard and I have trouble understanding the proof of Theorem 1.6.9.

The first part of the proof - that the image of the function is bounded is clear. However I don't understand how the proof for the existence of maximum works, specifically why formula 1.6.9 is justified. Why can it be stated that there exists a sequence
$ i \mapsto \boldsymbol{x_i}$ such that $\lim_{i\to\infty} f(\boldsymbol{x_i}) = M.$ ($M$ being the least upper bound of the image of $f$)

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since $M$ is the least supper bound of the image of $f$, by definition, on one hand, $f(\mathbf{x}) \leq M$, and on the other hand, for **any** $\varepsilon > 0$, there **must be** some $\mathbf{y} \in C$ such that $f(\mathbf{y}) > M - \varepsilon$.

---

There must be some $\mathbf{x}_1 \in C$ such that $M \geq f(\mathbf{x}_1) > M - 1$;
there must be some $\mathbf{x}_2 \in C$ such that $M \geq f(\mathbf{x}_2) > M - \frac{1}{2}$;
there must be some $\mathbf{x}_3 \in C$ such that $M \geq f(\mathbf{x}_3) > M - \frac{1}{3}$;
... ... ... ...

---

I hope that it helps.